# How to increase iOS deployment target version in Expo managed workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

When building for iOS in the Expo Managed workflow, the deployment target is automatically set to iOS 11.

Is there a way to increase the deployment target without having to eject from Expo Managed?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you are building with EAS in the managed workflow, you can achieve it with the [expo-build-properties](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/#pluginconfigtype) official plugin.
Install it and set your target version from the `app.config.js` file, for example :

```
plugins: [
    // ...other plugins
    [
      "expo-build-properties",
      {
        ios: {
          deploymentTarget: "15.0",
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
```

Note that the deployment targets are periodically raised by Expo when the SDK is upgraded.

Comment: make sure to `yarn expo prebuild --clean` (or `npx expo prebuild --clean` if not using yarn) to reflect appropriately if using the expo managed workflow

Comment: If anyone else comes here after _Oct-26, 2023_ and is using expo-notifications or expo-task-manager, the minimum target is now **13.4**, as [documented here](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/25063).